# JDBC with MySQL Connecting Very Slowly

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Currently I'm working in Java, and have been experimenting more with implementing a database into my project. Below is my current code to connect to the database (using one database, username, and password, hard-coded, as this is a personal):

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String connString = String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s:3306/%s?user=%s&password=%s", HOST, DB, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    long then = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Connecting... ");
    this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString);
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("\tTIME ELAPSED: " + (now - then) / 1000);
} catch(SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Couldn't get Connection");
    this.conn = null;
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    this.conn = null;
}
```

However, I've narrowed down that the `DriverManager.getConnection()` method is taking **23 seconds** every single time to the database I'm connecting to (even the very first connection establishment). I can guarantee that all `ResultSet` objects and connections are being properly closed, and that all connection information is valid.

I'm using my school's computer science provided MySQL account, and can verify that it is not slow to connect through any other means (MySQL Workbench, etc.).

**Is there anything that I'm missing that could be doing this?** All querying of the database after the initial connection is super fast, it's just the connection itself that is terribly slow. Thanks!

### UPDATE:

I started using connection pooling as mentioned in the comments (following Apache DBCP), and the problem still persists. Here's the code I'm using to set up the pooling:

```
ds = new BasicDataSource();
ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String connString = String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s:3306/%s", HOST, db);
ds.setUrl(connString);
ds.setUsername(USERNAME);
ds.setPassword(PASSWORD);
ds.setMaxActive(1000);
ds.setMaxWait(10000);
ds.setMaxIdle(10);
try {
    long then = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Connecting... ");
    this.conn = ds.getConnection();
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("\tTIME ELAPSED: " + (now - then) / 1000);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    this.conn = null;
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

### UPDATE 2:

It turns out that it was an issue with my home connection at the time, not any of the code.
Thank you all for your help!

Comment: try using connection pooling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it has something to do with HOST. Are you connecting using hostname? Try to map the hostname  to an IP in 'etc hosts' file if this is the case.

Check out Apache Commons DBCP, which allows you to pool database connections.
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/

Comment: The hostname is corectly mapped in ``/etc/hosts`` file, so I don't think that's the issue. I switched out the hostname with the IP to connect to as well, but the problem still exists.
I've thought about using connection pooling, though I figured I wanted to solve this issue anyway.

Comment: **UPDATE:** I used pooling (implemented with the link you gave me), and the problem persists. Using pooling, the database is taking about **40 seconds** to connect now.

Comment: @Nuuou: I can't see any problem with the attached snippet. I would advice you to run the same program in other machine to see if the problem persists.

Comment: It turns out that it was an issue with my home connection at the time, not any of the code. I tried it on a different network, and connecting works just fine. I'll check some settings on my network now. Thank you for your help!